# Need help on search_count() function in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

i'm creating a sample module like library management, and int that having a "stock" model i would like to get the count of the damaged books number from overall books in the library(e.g status of books are damaged, lended etc) i would like to get the count of the books that are in damaged condition from the model named "bookinfo"
i tried the below code but no issues . plz help on this.

**field in the model "stock":**

```
damaged_books=fields.Integer(compute='damage')
```

**code to get the count of damaged books from the model "bookinfo":**

```
@api.depends()        
def damage(self):        
    count = self.env['bookinfo.status'].search_count([('status','=','damage')])
    self.damaged_books = count
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
@api.one
def damage(self):
    count=self.env['bookinfo.status'].search_count([('status','=','damage')]) 
    self.damaged_books=count
```

Here I don't think you need to add the watch on any field so you don't need to use "@api.depends". It is used when you want to keep watch on other fields to calculate the field and store the values in database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried the following code instead of the above it works fine. res=self.env['bookinfo'].search([])

a=0

for x in res: if(x.status=='damage'):

a=a+1

self.damaged_books=a

Comment: Just a heads up that api.one is deprecated since Odoo V9! It is adviced to use api.multi with an ensure_one().This is written in the ORM API at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#module-openerp.api

Comment: Thank you @Yenthe for adding the info.